# PDO INNER JOIN returning 0 rows with proof of existing overlap

Tags: php, sql, inner-join

I am querying my database and trying to put together an inner join statement.  For some reason I can get a return value for $query and $query1, but $joinQuery turns up empty.  I'm not getting any errors when I run, so I don't understand how this is happening.

I think I read somewhere that capital letters in tables is an issue, but I have a similar query from another database on the same server which uses capital letters and is working great.(see $workingQuery)

Any ideas?  Please let me know if I should provide more information.

```
$query1 = $db->prepare("SELECT productName, unitRetailPrice, styleIDs, shippingWeight, styleNumber
                       FROM productImports
                       WHERE styleNumber = 1145") or die("could not display products");
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT productID, description, styleCode, colorID, sizeID, manID, imageFile, availableQuantity
                       FROM products
                       WHERE styleCode = 1145
                       ORDER BY productID $limit") or die("could not display products");

$joinQuery = $db->prepare("SELECT products.productID, products.description, products.styleCode, products.colorID, products.sizeID, products.manID, products.imageFile, products.availableQuantity, productImports.productName, productImports.unitRetailPrice 
                           FROM products
                           INNER JOIN productImports ON products.styleCode = productImports.styleNumber
                           ORDER BY productID");


$workingQuery = $db->prepare("SELECT workoutBasket.exID, workoutBasket.setIndex, workoutBasket.setCount, workoutBasket.durationPlan, workoutBasket.repsPlan, workoutBasket.weightPlan, workoutBasket.adaptationID, exercises.exName, exercises.exTypeID
                                FROM workoutBasket
                                INNER JOIN exercises ON workoutBasket.exID = exercises.exID
                                WHERE workoutBasket.workoutID = '$workoutID' ORDER BY exID ASC, setIndex ASC") or die("could not query workoutBasket");
```

Comment: Get rid of PDO and check your queries in raw mysql console

Comment: When I run in the query box on phpmyadmin, I get one result for each $query1 and $query, but when I run $joinQuery, it returns 0 rows

Comment: So your problem is irrelevant to PDO. though indeed it's quite strange.

Comment: Guessing capital letters are not the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what are you talking about.

Comment: For some reason, I imagine I read somewhere that capital letters in table names is an issue

Comment: You should imagine what particular kind of issue it is, and then decide, whether this issue is applicable for your case.